# restore sql dump into remote postgres machine

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i dump the .sql file into remote postgres machine!

Will the pg_restore will work for it to dump sql file. Please help

Code:
`pg_restore -h 192.168.0.190 -p 5432 -d postgre -U postgres C:/home/mydump.sql`

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) a `sql` dump needs to be "restored" using `psql`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pls suggest me if this command will work ```psql -h 192.168.0.190 -U postgres -p 5432 -d postgre -1 -f mydump.sql```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`psql -h 192.168.0.190 -U postgres -p 5432 -d postgre < mydump.sql`